# How do I compare a date range to values in a table?

Tags: ms-access-2010, date-range

I have a form where the user will plan material transfers based on how many days he wishes to plan ahead for. Today is Monday. Let's say he selects that he wants to plan for 2 days ahead - up until Tuesday and Wednesday. Therefore, he would enter "3" into the text box on the form (he must include today as one of the days in order to make it possible for users to only consider the current day). My reports needs to understand that he wants to use the dates 6/1/2015, 6/2/2015, and 6/3/2015.

```
[SelectedDays] = 3
```

Therefore, `[SelectedRange] = 6/1/2015 6/2/2015 6/3/2015`

The table I am checking against has jobs that show intervals of work time as date and time. I can parse this to return only the date.

```
Job       Run Date
A         6/2/2015
A         6/3/2015
A         6/4/2015
```

How would I write a query that checks the Selected Range against the Run Date and ultimately returns **the number of days that the job is running *within* the selected range?** In the example above, I need the final output to be 2 because from 6/1/2015 - 6/3/2015 Job A is running for 2 days *within* that range.

Comment: Why not Job B? It is also running for `6/3/2015`, which is included in the range, is it not?

Comment: Oh my, that's a big error on my part. Sorry! In reality, yes there are multiple jobs but I wanted to simplify to a single job. The goal of this is to simply figure out how to compare these date ranges. I will fix my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BETWEEN` keyword in the `FROM` clause to get the data you need. Something along the lines of,

```
SELECT
    Count(someField) As TotalJobs
FROM
    yourTableName
WHERE
    yourDateField 
    BETWEEN Date() AND DateAdd("d", [Forms]![yourFormName]![SelectedDays] - 1, Date())
```

This should give you the count of Jobs, between `Today` and `Today + 3`